# Textarea cannot append to after typeing. Also, cannot append new text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery. While learning this I ran into a few issues. I wanted to know what I am doing wrong here. I am using a textarea element to type in. When I run the jQuery script below it will post to the dive I called read-post no problem But I cannot run the click Function to append to the textarea. Also, if I start typing in the text area I cannot append to the textarea. However, If I start frest I can append to the textarea no problem.

```js
$(".btn-post").click(function() {
  $("div").append($("textarea").val() + '<br />');
  $("textarea").val('');
  $("textarea").html('');
});

$("div #icon > span").click(function() {
  $(".textarea").append($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row post-body">
  <div class="col-2 p-0 post-img-holder my-auto p-1">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 text-center">
      <div class="embed-responsive-item">
        <a href="uuid">
          <img class="post-img" src="$imgPath">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 p-0">
    <textarea class="post-input" type="textblock" placeholder="What do you want to share, uuid?"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row post-footer">
  <div class="col-10 float-left dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle emoji-icon" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></a>
    <div id="emoji-icon" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <span>&#x1F600;</span><span>&#x1F603;</span><span>&#x1F604;</span><span>&#x1F601;</span><span>&#x1F606;</span>
      <span>&#x1F605;</span><span>&#x1F923;</span><span>&#x1F602;</span><span>&#x1F642;</span><span>&#x1F643;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 float-right">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-post" type="post">Post</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: put your html too please

Comment: sure, no problem. I will edit this post.

Comment: @Çağrı - There you go.

Comment: @Çağrı - that script overwrites that text that maybe already in the box. It's not appending to the text. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I added answer .

Comment: @Çağrı - thank you so much for your help! I posted a comment below. What books should I pick up to learn more about jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/hmwLox17/
u have two missing one of them is your icon id is #emoji-icon but u wrote just #icon,
second missing is u should write $("textarea") bu u wrote $(".textarea")

> $(".textarea") means u have an element whose class is textarea
>
> #icon means u have element whose id is icon

```
 $("div #emoji-icon > span").click(function(){
       $("textarea").val($("textarea").val()+$(this).text());
   });
```

Comment: Thank you! It works in the functional code. I just edited it to be a little easier on reading. I have the script working. However, your above code fixed the issue after posting whatever I wrote in the textarea. Thank you! But one issue remains appending to text from the emjoi dropdown to the textarea.

Comment: If I first pick the emoji I can then write and post. but if I write then select an emoji it won't append.

Comment: edited code in answer just  make new value with past one value plus new one.

Comment: I ran the code in the editor and it does the same thing that I am experiencing. I really appreciate your help! You're a rockstar.

Comment: Dude! You are a SUPERHERO! So, I see that you have two methods adapted to the code. with the basic javascript + append. I didn't that you could do that. What do you suggest to read so I can learn more about what I am doing? Right now I picked this up because I am stuck at home. Last semester I learned PHP and got an A++ in that class.